# Jsoup - The method connect(String) is undefined for the type Jsoup

Tags: java, eclipse, jsoup

So I'm trying to install Jsoup to Eclipse.

1. Made a user library (Window->Preferences, Java->build path->user library, new->name("JsoupLibrary")->add JARs) the JARs. The JARs I downloaded from http://jsoup.org/download
2. Build the path to my project. (right click project->build path->configure build path, add library->user library->next->JsoupLibrary-finish)

So i tried to run the example they gave on their website (see code) I could import Document and Elements. But it keeps giving an error on "connect". Am i doing something wrong?? Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method connect(String) is undefined for the type Jsoup

    at JsoupTesting.Jsoup.main(Jsoup.java:12)
```

Jsoup test:

```
package JsoupTesting;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class Jsoup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/").get();
        Elements newsHeadlines = doc.select("#mp-itn b a");

    }

}
```

Comment: How about `right click project->build path->configure build path, add library->Add External Jars_>(select jar with Jsoup and confirm)`?

Comment: I got the same error. I think he sees the library, cause Eclipse does import the two other classes: Documents and Elements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is that your class is also named `Jsoup` so compiler in this code

```
Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/")
```

tries to use `connect(String)` method from your class, not from `org.jsoup.Jsoup` class, and since there is no such method in your class you see the error. To remove this problem change name of your class to something else like

```
public class JsoupDemo {
   ...
}
```

and add import to `org.jsoup.Jsoup` which has method you want to invoke.

Comment: Ty very much, your suggestion did the trick. had to put in the org.jsoup.Jsoup manually though, couldn't hover connect and click to import it for some reason.